# Group array items based on a key's value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have an array of data as follows

```
const data = [
            {
                "SurveyGroupID": 28,
                "SurveyGroupTypeID": 4,
                "SurveyID": 23,
                "SurveyGroupSequence": 1,
                "SurveyQuestionSequence": 1,
                "Question": "What is your reason for visiting our practice?",
                "DataTypeName": "Memo",
                "DataTypeID": 4,
                "Required": true
            },
            {
                "SurveyGroupID": 28,
                "SurveyGroupTypeID": 4,
                "SurveyID": 23,
                "SurveyGroupSequence": 2,
                "SurveyQuestionSequence": 2,
                "Question": "What is your height?",
                "DataTypeName": "String",
                "DataTypeID": 2,
                "Required": true
            },
            {
                "SurveyGroupID": 28,
                "SurveyGroupTypeID": 4,
                "SurveyID": 23,
                "SurveyGroupSequence": 1,
                "SurveyQuestionSequence": 3,
                "Question": "What is your weight?",
                "DataTypeName": "Integer",
                "DataTypeID": 3,
                "Required": true
            },
]
```

I need to **`group the array based on a key's value`**. That is i need to group together array items to a **`fields`** key which having same `SurveyGroupSequence` value

resulting into

```
[
  {
    "fields": [
      {
        "SurveyGroupTypeID": "1",
        "Question": "What is your reason for visiting our practice?"
      },
      {
        "SurveyGroupTypeID": "1",
        "Question": "What is your weight?"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "fields": [
      {
        "SurveyGroupTypeID": "2",
        "Question": "What is your height?"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How could i achieve this? Thank you.

## What i have tried

```
    const ar1 = [];
    data.forEach((Element, index) => {
      const fields = [{
        "SurveyGroupTypeID": Element.SurveyGroupTypeID,
        "Question": Element.Question
      }]
      ar1.push({
        fields : fields
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```js
const surveyGroupTypeMap = {};

data.forEach(({SurveyGroupTypeID, Question}) => {
    if (surveyGroupTypeMap[SurveyGroupTypeID]) {
        surveyGroupTypeMap[SurveyGroupTypeID].push(Question);
    } else {
        surveyGroupTypeMap[SurveyGroupTypeID] = [Question];
    }
});

const result = [];

Object.keys(surveyGroupTypeMap).forEach(id => {
    result.push({
        fields: surveyGroupTypeMap[id].map(question => ({
            SurveyGroupTypeID: id, Question: question
        }))
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Forgot to give you a kudos at past :) , because you deserve one ::)

Answer (score 1):

Uses an object map to collect by key SurveyGroupSequence as SurveyGroupTypeID:

```js
function groupByID(data){
  console.log(
    Object.values(data.reduce((acc,{SurveyGroupSequence: SurveyGroupTypeID, Question})=>{
        if( acc[SurveyGroupTypeID] )
          acc[SurveyGroupTypeID].push({SurveyGroupTypeID, Question})
        else
          acc[SurveyGroupTypeID] = [{SurveyGroupTypeID, Question}]
        return acc;
    },{}))
  )
}


const data = [
            {
                "SurveyGroupID": 28,
                "SurveyGroupTypeID": 4,
                "SurveyID": 23,
                "SurveyGroupSequence": 1,
                "SurveyQuestionSequence": 1,
                "Question": "What is your reason for visiting our practice?",
                "DataTypeName": "Memo",
                "DataTypeID": 4,
                "Required": true
            },
            {
                "SurveyGroupID": 28,
                "SurveyGroupTypeID": 4,
                "SurveyID": 23,
                "SurveyGroupSequence": 2,
                "SurveyQuestionSequence": 2,
                "Question": "What is your height?",
                "DataTypeName": "String",
                "DataTypeID": 2,
                "Required": true
            },
            {
                "SurveyGroupID": 28,
                "SurveyGroupTypeID": 4,
                "SurveyID": 23,
                "SurveyGroupSequence": 1,
                "SurveyQuestionSequence": 3,
                "Question": "What is your weight?",
                "DataTypeName": "Integer",
                "DataTypeID": 3,
                "Required": true
            },
]
groupByID(data)
```